# Determine dlog in quotient rings of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

Question:

> Determine $\operatorname{dlog}_x (x^2 + 1)$ in $\Bbb Z_5[x]/\langle\,x^3 + x + 1\,\rangle$

So I know the elements of $F = \Bbb Z_5[x]/\langle\,x^3 + x + 1\,\rangle $ are of the form $ax^2 + bx + c \bmod x^3 + x + 1$ ($a, b, c \in \Bbb Z_5$). I know how to calculate inverse of elements in F and all, but I dont know how to solve the discrete log problem. Any solution, partial or complete, would be great. Thanks...

Comment: See [here](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/dma/20/2/article-p231.xml) how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $x^1 = x$.
- $x^2= x^2$.
- $x^3 \equiv -x-1 \equiv 4x+4$. Here we use that $x^3 + x +1 \equiv 0$ in this field (assuming it is a field, haven't checked), and coefficients are mod 5.
- $x^4 \equiv 4x^2 + 4x$.
- $x^5 \equiv 4x^3 + 4x^2 \equiv 4(-x-1)+ 4x^2 \equiv 4x^2 + x +1$.
- $x^6 \equiv 4x^3 + x^2 + x \equiv 4(-x-1) + x^2 +x \equiv x^2 + 2x + 1$.
- $x^7 \equiv x^3 + 2x^2 + x \equiv (-x-1) + 2x^2 + x \equiv 2x^2 + 4$.
- $x^8 \equiv 2x^3 + 4x \equiv 2(-x-1) + 4x = 2x+3$.
- $x^9 \equiv 2x^2 + 3x$.
- $x^{10} \equiv 2x^3 + 3x \equiv 2(-x-1) + 3x \equiv x + 3$.
- $x^{11} \equiv x^2 + 3x$.
- $x^{12} \equiv x^3 + 3x^2 \equiv -x-1 + 3x^2 = 3x^2 + 4x + 4$.
- $x^{13} \equiv 3x^3 + 4x^2 + 4x \equiv 3(-x-1) + 4x^2 + 4x \equiv 4x^2 + x + 2$.
- $x^{14} \equiv 4x^3 + x^2 + 2x \equiv 4(-x-1) + x^2 + 2x \equiv x^2 + 3x +1$.

etc. Continue until we get $x^n \equiv x^2+1$, and the answer is $n$.

Or use a computer algebra package, or write your own program...

Comment: Note that this is doable at all with such a small ($5^3 =125$) elements, but a computer program is better, though this is nice practice. You could use optimisations like baby step, giant-step etc.

Comment: I see. I was just having trouble getting started. I understood how I can use shank's algorithm. Thank you!

Comment: @AnkitKumar You're welcome. Shank's is about factorisation isn't it? Or do you mean another one?

Comment: No, no. I just meant the baby step giant step algo only

Comment: @AnkitKumar I see that [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) is also due to Shanks.

Comment: Yess...........

Answer (score 0):

One could also observe that we have  $x^2+1=-1/x$
in ${\bf Z}_5[x]/(x^3+x+1)$. Therefore the dlog
of $x^2+1$ is equal to the dlog of $-1$ minus the dlog of $x$.
Since the constant coefficient of $x^3+x+1$ is equal to $1$, we
have $x\cdot x^5\cdot x^{25} = -1$. It follows that the dlog
of $x^2+1$ is $31-1=30$.

Comment: Unrelated, but can you repost your answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3808529/ on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809632/group-membership-test-for-permutations (where it belongs)? Thanks! (Feel free to flag this comment as obsolete afterwards.)